# Who decides on US congressional hearings topics and schedule?

Tags: united-states, congress

Who has an authority to decide on US congressional hearing topics and persons to 
be questioned? I am mostly interested in the answer for investigative hearings.

Is any way for public to affect that process?

Comment: Generally speaking, a Senate or House Committee decides on holding a meeting. See e.g. CRS Report RL 30548, *Hearings in the U. S. Senate: A Guide for Preparation and Procedure*. One way for the public to affect that process would be by contacting representatives who are members of the committee.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the power of the calendar that makes the Speaker of the House and the Senate Majority Leader so powerful - they get to decide what issues will be brought up in a given session.

Once the issue is placed on the calendar, individual committee chairman - usually the ranking member of the majority and minority parties, decide what hearings and committee meetings will be held on a given topic.

As to influencing hearings, really there are only a few things *you* as private citizen (or a lobbyist) for that matter can do:

- Write / Contact your Member to request hearings on a matter
- Meet with your Member to convince them that you should testify in such a hearing, if one exists. Typically, this only happens if you are a notable expert in the field, have a particularly good sob story, or are Angela Jolie.
- Raise lots of money to air ads on Fox/MSNBC/CNN that say "Here's a problem. Call your Congressman at (202)224-3121 (yes, that's the number) and demand they hold hearings into the matter.

And, last but not least:

- Resign yourself to the fact that the United States Congress is so busy as to make it unlikely to have hearings on a matter of importance to you.

Hearings are mostly opportunities for members to go on record anyway. If you really want action, you contact your member privately, convince of them of a need, and see if you can quietly sneak a bill through *without* going public. As Hedrick Smith's [Iron Law of Politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/in-the-u-s-when-a-policy-issue-is-more-relevant-in-public-opinion-does-the-in) implies, the less publicity your issues generates, the more likely it is for action to be possible in the first place.